# Where does formData ever get used in the controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've seen many examples of uploading files asynchronously using AJAX and ASP.NET MVC, and I can't figure out if/how the Javascript `FormData` object ever gets used in the controller. The examples I see look like

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("something", e.target.files[0]););
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("upload","someController")',
        data: formData,
```

---

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> upload ( )
    {

        try
        {
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
                if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
                {
```

but I'm confused about how to `formData` is ever used in the controller. If it is used, how does it get inside a controller that has a blank parameter list?

Comment: I'm confused, why would the serverside have access to the formData object directly, and not just the uploaded files in `Request.Files` ?

Comment: I understand that. All the examples use `Request.Files`, which makes me confused about why `formData` is needed in the first place. What does it ever do?

Comment: It's needed to get the files in the browser, and send them to the server

Comment: [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: `FormData` is client side. Its just a client side method for constructing name/value pairs that are sent to the server. `FormData` itself is not used by the controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think I get it. So when I do  `Request.Files[file];` in the server the variable `file` is the key in `formData.append(key, value)`. Is that right?`

Comment: Basically yes. [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) might help you to understand better.